# Master from upstream, topic branches - mine

Tags: git

I forked a repo into my github account.

Then i did

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:********/*********.git
```

Now i have `upstream` remote - the original, and `origin` - my fork.

And my `master` branch is tracking `origin/master`.

I am never going to push to `origin/master`, as all pull requests i will do will be from topic branches.

At the same time i will often pull the latest changes from `upstream/master` to make new topic branches from it.

So i want to configure git in such way that:

- my local branch `master` is tracking `upstream/master`
- when i am in `master` branch and i do `git push`, this will fail, because `upstream` is read-only.
- when i am in `master` branch and i do `git pull`, i will pull the latest changes from `upstream/master` and i will immediately be able to do `git checkout -b my-new-topic-branch` having forked from the latest `upstream/master`.

Any comments on the workflow? How do set git for this?

Being in `master` i did:

```
git branch -u upstream/master
```

But when i switched to a topic branch:

```
git remote show origin
...
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master  pushes to master  (fast-forwardable)
...
```

**UPDATE:**

The solution:

```
(c8cc3a6) » git branch -d master                                   
Deleted branch master (was c8cc3a6).

(c8cc3a6) » git branch --track master upstream/master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from upstream.

(c8cc3a6) » git remote show origin
...
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master                       pushes to master                       (fast-forwardable)
...

(c8cc3a6) » git remote show upstream
...
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)

(c8cc3a6) » git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

(master) » git pull
Already up-to-date.

(master) » git push
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

(master) » git checkout -b test-branch
Switched to a new branch 'test-branch'

(test-branch) » git push
...
To git@github.com:********/*******.git
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> test-branch
```

Or a more understandable way:

```
(test-branch) » git branch -d master
Deleted branch master (was c8cc3a6).

(test-branch) » git checkout -b master upstream/master  
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from upstream.
Switched to a new branch 'master'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.git/config` on your local repository, make the `[branch "master"]` section look like this:

```
[branch "master"]
remote = upstream
merge = refs/heads/master
```

This will handle items 1 and 3 (tracking and pull configuration). I'm not sure there's a way to perfectly accomplish item 2, but you will probably find that, since `upstream` isn't your repository, it will refuse pushes from you (unless the owner of that repo allows random contributors to push, which I'm not sure can be done on github...).

Comment: I got this configuration running `git branch --track master upstream/master`. I've updated the question with the solution. Thank you!